# Can not extract String from try-catch nested for loop

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing, try-catch, nodes

I am parsing through an XML file to get the child nodes, which does work. I simply want to put that in to a String and pass it out of the for loop but when I pass it out, it does not put all of the child nodes in to the String, and sometimes it puts nothing in the String. If it use System.out.println(data) in under the if statement then it works fine. I want to get data out of the if loop and pass it on. Here is my code...

```
public class Four {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Four four = new Four();
        String a = null;
        try {
            Document doc = four.doIt();
            String b = four.getString(doc);

            System.out.println(b);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Document doIt() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        String rawData = null;

        URL url = new URL("http://feeds.cdnak.neulion.com/fs/nhl/mobile/feeds/data/20140401.xml");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);

        return doc;
    }

    public String getString(Document doc) {
        String data = null;

        NodeList cd = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("game");
        for (int i = 0; i < cd.getLength(); i++) {
          Node item = cd.item(i);
          System.out.println("==== " + item.getNodeName() + " ====");
          NodeList children = item.getChildNodes();
          for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
            Node child = children.item(j);


            if (child.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                data = child.getNodeName().toString() + ":" + child.getTextContent().toString();    
                // if I System.out.println(data) here, it shows all everything
                I want, when I return data it shows nothing but ===game===
            }
        }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try debugging it with your debugger as the value should not change between when you return the value and when the caller gets the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems stemming from the try statement in combination with the loop. However, I am not sure your getString function works the way you think it does. Look closely at the statement that assigns data:

```
data = child.getNodeName().toString() + ":" + child.getTextContent().toString();
```

For each iteration in the loop, the data variable is completely re-assigned. Your return value is only going to contain data from the last node that was processed.

I think what you probably meant to do is concatenate the node's value to the end of your string. You might write it this way:

```
data += "|" + child.getNodeName().toString() + ":" + child.getTextContent().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `b` outside the `try` block :

```
    String b = null;
    try {
        Document doc = four.doIt();
        b = four.getString(doc);

        System.out.println(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will let you use its value outside the `try` block.